# Testing a Generator in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, generator

I programmed a very simple generator in Python 3.4:

```
class Gen:
  def __init__(self, xml_lines, attribs):
    #...

  def _get_values(self, xml_line):
    # get only specific "attribs" from a line in a "xml"

  def values(self):
    for line in self.xml_lines:
      yield self._get_values(line)
```

The code works when I use a for loop to consume the generated values:

```
reader = Gen(...):
for v in reader.values():
   print(v)
```

But I'm now trying to create a unit test, and for that, I'd need to get each value at a time (outside a loop). I'm trying something like this:

```
import unittest
#...
reader = Gen(...):
v = reader.values()
self.assertIsNone(v)
```

When I try that, I always get a

```
AssertionError: <generator object next_values at 0x7fe2a5f9e3f0> is not None
```

So, when I call the **values** myself, it return something (is it a pointer?) instead of the generated value.

As I'm considering I'm using a basic generator pattern, my question is a little broader then my own code: what's the proper way to test a Python Generator?

Comment: If you want your class's instances to be iterable you should be implementing `__iter__` and `__next__`, see e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter. Aside from that, you have the issue that `next_value()` is creating a brand new generator, not giving you the next value from an existing one (the name is therefore a little misleading).

Comment: @jonrsharpe Got it! I'm changing the method name to reflect your important observation... I was getting the method call wrong. Thanks. But I don't really thing I need the `__iter__` and `__next__` methods in this case, as the `yield` gives me all at once.

Comment: You don't need `__next__` necessarily, but if you rename he method to `__iter__` you can then iterate directly over the instance rather than explicitly calling a method to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Write unittest for function with yield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37956435/write-unittest-for-function-with-yield)

Answer (score 9):

A generator is meant to be iterated through.  You can use the [next()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) function to get the next value of the generator.  Be aware that if your generator has exhausted it's values, it will raise a [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.StopIteration) exception.

```
reader = Gen(...):
values = reader.values()
v = next(values)
self.assertIsNone(v)
```

Comment: Although this will work, I suspect that the OP is hoping for an implementation such that `next(reader)` would generate `None`.

Comment: Oh man! I thought I've tried that. Thanks anyway @Brendan. What is strange to me is that I couldn't find any information on the "<generator object...>"... not even a "dir(v)" was helpful! Can you share your source?

Comment: @Nigini [Here[(https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) -- I can't link directly to the point in the page, but search the page for "generator functions".  They always return an iterator object.  You can call `.next()` on that object to get the next value (or use the built-in `next()` function on it).  Possibly one of the things that could be better documented in the python docs.

Answer (score 5):

I needed to unit-test a generator myself, so I created this helper function:

```
def generator_tester(generator_iterator_to_test, expected_values):   
    range_index = 0
    for actual in generator_iterator_to_test:
        assert range_index + 1 <= len(expected_values), 'Too many values returned from range'
        assert expected_values[range_index] == actual
        range_index += 1

    assert range_index == len(expected_values), 'Too few values returned from range'
```

Here's an example of using it:

```
generator_tester(
    Gen(...),
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
)
```

Comment: How about creating a list from the generator and then checking it against your expectation?: `assert list(Gen(...)) == [1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Problem with this is, the generator may not actually be a generator. Could be returning a list.

Comment: Missing a closing bracket on the last line

Comment: Ooh, thanks @PetarMarkovic. I've added that in now.

Answer (score 2):

Given that you can only test a finite number of outputs from a generator, you may just turn the iterator to a list by:

```
self.assertEqual(list(your_generator_function_call(your_inputs)), list_of_exepcted_outputs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to check that the value produced by the `return` in the generator was valid, and I needed to know how the yielded values differed from the expected ones when the lenght was different. I ended up using a pretty big helper function, which reads up to 6 values that are produced but not expected, or the other way around, and displays them. Here it is:

```py
from unittest import TestCase


class MISSING:
    pass


    def _generator_tester(
        self,
        iterator,
        expected_value_list,
        expected_returned_value=MISSING,
    ):
        """
        Helper method to test a generator.

        Args:
            iterator (Iterator):
                generator iterator to test
            expected_value_list (list):
                list of the values the generator should produce
            expected_returned_value (any):
                the final values returned by the generator
        """
        expected_value_iterator = iter(expected_value_list)

        try:
            for expected in expected_value_iterator:
                actual = next(iterator)
                self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
        except StopIteration:
            # Generator iterator is too short.
            #
            # len(iterator) < len(expected_value_iterator)
            #
            # Let's see what values were expected
            remaining_expected_values = [expected]
            for value in iterator:
                remaining_expected_values.append(value)
                if len(remaining_expected_values) == 8:
                    remaining_expected_values[-1] = Ellipsis
                    break
            self.fail(f"Too few values. Expected: {remaining_expected_values}")

        try:
            remaining_values = [next(iterator)]
        except StopIteration as stop_iteration:
            # Generator iterator is the right length
            #
            # len(iterator) == len(expected_value_iterator)
            #
            # Let's check the return value of the iterator
            if expected_returned_value != MISSING:
                self.assertEqual(stop_iteration.value, expected_returned_value)
        else:
            # Generator iterator is too long
            #
            # len(iterator) > len(expected_value_iterator)
            #
            # Let's see what are the extra values of the generator
            for value in iterator:
                remaining_values.append(value)
                if len(remaining_values) == 8:
                    remaining_values[-1] = Ellipsis
                    break
            self.fail(f"Too many values: {remaining_values}")
```